# Position fixed dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I created a position fixed dropdown menu but when I go to select a drop-down content the whole menu bar collapses. Please see attached pictures.

How can I create a proper position fixed drop-down menu where the drop-down content does not affect the menu bar?

[image: Error Exmple]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #003746;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 42px;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 42px;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: static;
  background-color: #003746;
  min-width: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: green
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img class="center" width="80" height="50" title="Example"></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn">AAA</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a>AAA - AAA</a>
      <a>AAA1 - AAA1</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn">BBB</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a>BBB - BBB</a>
      <a>BBB1 - BBB1</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You say _see attached pictures_ twice but there aren't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `position: absolute;` on the *dropdown-content* class. Then it will work. `position: static;` is the initial position of any element.

Oh, and remove the `overflow: hidden;` from the *ul* element. If you keep that property on it, you basicly are saying. *"Anything that goes out of my container, hide!".*

If you keep that property on it, the *dropdown-content* menu will be set to `display: block;` but not visible because it gets hidden by its parent element (the `<ul>` element).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #003746;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 42px;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 42px;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #003746;
  min-width: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: green
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img class="center" width="80" height="50" title="Example"></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn">AAA</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a>AAA - AAA</a>
      <a>AAA1 - AAA1</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn">BBB</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a>BBB - BBB</a>
      <a>BBB1 - BBB1</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```